# converting decimal number into long integer

Tags: php

I have the number `43.95`
I want to convert it to the become `4395`.
How do I simply do this in 1 line?

I currently have it like this:

```
$priceDollars = intval($priceSum);
$priceCents = $priceSum - $priceDollars;
$priceCents = round($priceCents, 2);
$priceCents = substr((string)$priceCents, 2);

print_r("$priceDollars and $priceCents");

$priceDollars=(string)$priceDollars;
$priceCents=(string)$priceCents;
$price = $priceDollars.$priceCents;
$price = (int)$price;

print_r($price);
```

Comment: You can just multiply it with 100?

Comment: or in general you can use $pricesum as string and replace the decimal point before reconverting to int ... something like: `intval( str_replace(".", "", $pricesum) );`

Comment: Nathan Rawiri "If an answer solved your problem, consider accepting the answer. Here's [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). Then return here and do the same with the tick/check-mark till it turns green. This informs the community, that a solution was found. Otherwise, others may think the question is still open and may want to post (more) answers. You'll earn points and others will be encouraged to help you. Welcome to Stack!"

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$dec = 43.95;
echo $int = (int)str_replace('.', '', (string)$dec);//4395
```

Answer (score 1):

a) If numbers after decimal will always be 2 then multiply by 100

```
<?php
  $price = 43.95;
  echo $price*100;
```

https://3v4l.org/CN9T4

b) Otherwise, you can use the @Diego De Vita code given in the comments under your question.

```
intval( str_replace(".", "", $pricesum) );
```

https://3v4l.org/dUXm2